# How to control & adjust the sound volume in windows 7?

Tags: c#, windows-7, audio

I would like to control and adjust sound volume of windows 7 in C# Win Form? Any tips, how is this be done?

Comment: Why do you want to override the user's control?

Comment: @Richard the idea of automation is a great one, using the mouse takes too long. at least that is my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to use winmm API. You can try this link.

[Volume Control](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isvvba/thread/05dc2d35-1d45-4837-8e16-562ee919da85)

I have used NAudio for visualization. Not sure if that might help you.
With WPF it should be fairly simple, you can either use MediaElement or MediaPlayer and bind it to a Slider.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here : http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial176_Get-and-set-the-wave-sound-volume.html

You can also use NAudio wich is a managed wrapper for the IAudioMeterInformation interface.

More info on IAudioMeterInformation interface : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368227%28VS.85%29.aspx

NAudio projet on CodePlex : http://naudio.codeplex.com/