# How to control master volume with c# wpf applications?

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, volume

I am trying to control the master volume with a wpf applications, I did some research on this, and most of the solutions are for window form applications, which I can't apply on wpf. Even they're both c#, but wpf don't have handle, which made all the solution unusable. So I am here to see do anyone here know how to control master volume in a wpf application?

-- I actually have plan B for this, if there is not any convenience way to do this. Maybe achieve it by coding a virtual key press? Like pressing the mute key on my keyboard but do it programmatically? Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to control & adjust the sound volume in windows 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341344/how-to-control-adjust-the-sound-volume-in-windows-7)

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13139478/4934541